# "∞" symbol not working with Raleway Font

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I'm designing a screen to be used in a mobile application. The font I've chosen to use is Raleway. In the screen I'm designing, I need to show the infinity "∞" symbol. My problem is, whenever I add the "∞" symbol, it does not take up the Raleway font, instead it takes up Helvetica Neue font. Any ideas on why I cannot get the infinity symbol to show up in the same Raleway font I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lemniscate is not a character of the font. https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway

Comment: I'll add: Not all "custom fonts contains all characters". If the character is not present in the target font, you have to find a look alike font for that character, or draw it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why others say the lemniscate is not part of the font. Character 8734 shows up in my copy of Raleway, downloaded through typecatcher, which I believe connects to the google sources. Maybe I'm all messed up but only so many of my fonts have the lemniscate, and Raleway is one. Whether the software you happen to be using can make use of it, or whether I happen to have a newer, more complete version of Raleway? Or maybe I'm missing something? I wonder if you try to obtain a newer copy.

To double check that I am not just being presented with a substitute from another font family, I opened up fonts.google.com and copied a lemniscate into the "type here to preview text line, along with a couple of glyphs I know are not part of Raleway. Only the lemniscate showed up. I did essentially the same in Scribus which does not do substitutions. Again only the raleway lemniscate showed.